# Организация структуры базы данных

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Есть таблица Messages, у которой есть столбцы: Id, AuthorId, RecipientId, Message. Я хочу добавить возможность прикреплять к сообщению документы. Создал таблицу Documents: Id, LocalPath, Hash. Всё бы ничего, но если прикреплено будет несколько документов к сообщению, то просто столбец DocumentId не подойдёт, тк нужно хранить массив. Делать отношение один ко многим - тоже не вариант (хранить дубли, как мне кажется, будет слишком тяжело, когда сообщений будет слишком много). У меня в голове лишь один вариант - хранить массив в виде json. Таким образом, появится столбец Documents типа Text, предполагающий null, в котором будет храниться json, при десериализации которого будет разворачиваться массив Id документов. Подскажите, приемлем ли такой вариант хранения? Есть ли другие варианты?

P.S. Код пишу на C# + entityframework

Upd:

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public int RecipientId { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LocalPath { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

а как вариант создать третью таблицу ?

messages: id,author_id,recipient_id, message

documents: ...

message_documents: id message_id document_id

Comment: Да, я тоже думал об этом варианте. Какой вариант будет более выгоден с точки зрения дальнейшего взаимодействия с бд? Обновил вопрос и добавил вариант, который, в теории, должен создать таблицу, о которой вы говорите

Comment: По опыту скажу что вариант с JSON не очень. Удобно, что сразу можно достать и всё (могу ошибаться).

Мы как-то переделывали базу в которой тоже в одной колонке JSON строка хранилась. Переделывали из-за того что база выросла. 

По мне вариант с третей таблицей(которая свяжет сообщения и документы) куда проще будет поддерживать, чем JSON колонку 

У нас,правда, стэк другой был: PHP

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Допустим потребуется изменения в документах сообщения, если выбрать вариант с JSON, то при получении старых данных не будет новой колонки - это добавлять новую проверку в код или же перебирать старые  данные и добавлять новую колонку 

Если же выбрать вариант с третей таблицей, то просто добавляешь новую колонку и во всех данных эта колонка будет существовать

Comment: Вариант с третьей таблицей нужен если одинаковые документы могут быть прикреплены к разным сообщениям. А если документы уникальны и к каждому сообщению прикрепляются свои, то достаточно в `Document` добавить `MessageId`.